# Can't change blue background in XAML Accordion

Tags: wpf, xaml, background, accordion

I am trying to use the accordion control in XAML but am unable to change the dark blue background that is used as default. I've manage to stumble upon a few other people having the same problem but with no solutions posted. The only answer I have found thus far involves using Expression Studio, but I unfortunately do not own a copy.

See below the designer code, there's not a whole lot there at the moment, I've tried setting the background property on each element but get no result on any of them.

```
<Window x:Class="Test.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window1" Height="289" 
    Width="500" 
    xmlns:my="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Layout.Toolkit">
    <Grid>
        <my:Accordion HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
            <my:AccordionItem x:Name="item1" Header="Item 1">
                <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                </Grid>
            </my:AccordionItem>
            <my:AccordionItem x:Name="item2" Header="Item 2">

            </my:AccordionItem>
            <my:AccordionItem x:Name="item3" Header="Item 3">

            </my:AccordionItem>
        </my:Accordion>        
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this [MSDN Forum thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-us/wpf/thread/46FFD9A7-5759-40F8-828F-159B4BDC69B5) of someone having the same problem. Also be aware this control is of [Preview](http://wpf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Quality%20Bands) quality which according to CodePlex is equivalant to an Alpha release.

From above link:

> The key part is binding to the actual outer grid.  For some reason, the accordion item isn't providing a width/height for the inner grid to stretch to, so you have to bind it to something "higher up" so to speak.

---

I tested it and it does work, It does give designer errors of `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` It does compile and run though.

```
<Grid>
    <my:Accordion HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <my:AccordionItem x:Name="item1" Header="Item 1">
            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Background="White" 
                Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Grid}}, Path=ActualWidth}"
                Height="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type Grid}}, Path=ActualHeight}">
            </Grid>
        </my:AccordionItem>
        <my:AccordionItem x:Name="item2" Header="Item 2">
            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Background="White"  
                Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Grid}}, Path=ActualWidth}"
                Height="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type Grid}}, Path=ActualHeight}">
            </Grid>
        </my:AccordionItem>
        <my:AccordionItem x:Name="item3" Header="Item 3">
            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Background="White" 
                Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Grid}}, Path=ActualWidth}"
                Height="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type Grid}}, Path=ActualHeight}">
            </Grid>
        </my:AccordionItem>
    </my:Accordion>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick :) After building once the error is no longer shown in my designer either.

Comment: @int0x90 Glad to be of some help.